# Right way of deleting child object in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have function, which takes Scene object and add it if there is no Scene with such Id or update it in another case:

```
public void AddOrUpdateScene(Scene scene)
{
    using (var dbContext = new QuestContext())
    {
        if (scene.Id == 0)
        {
            dbContext.Scenes.Add(scene);
        }
        else
        {
            dbContext.Entry(scene).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        foreach (var answer in scene.AnswerChildren)
        {
            if (answer.Id == 0)
            {
                dbContext.Answers.Add(answer);
            }
            else
            {
                dbContext.Entry(answer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        dbContext.Quests.First(x => x.Id == scene.QuestId).DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

The problem is deleting Answers in this code. 
Let's say I have 3 answers in my db where ids are 1, 2 and 3, attached to my Scene with Id == 1.
If scene passed to my function has answers with id 1 and 2, that means I have to delete answer with Id == 3 from my database so I edited code in that way:

```
public void AddOrUpdateScene(Scene scene)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new QuestContext())
            {
                dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var allAnswers = dbContext.Answers.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ParentSceneId == scene.Id).ToList();
                var ids = new List<int>();
                var answersToDelete = new List<Answer>();
                foreach (var answer in allAnswers.Where(answer => !scene.AnswerChildren.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(answer.Id)))
                {
                    ids.Add(answer.Id);
                    answersToDelete.Add(answer);
                    scene.AnswerChildren.Add(answer);
                }

                if (scene.Id == 0)
                {
                    dbContext.Scenes.Add(scene);
                }
                else
                {
                    dbContext.Entry(scene).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                foreach (var answer in scene.AnswerChildren)
                {
                    if (answer.Id == 0)
                    {
                        dbContext.Answers.Add(answer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (ids.Contains(answer.Id))
                        {
                            dbContext.Answers.Attach(answer);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dbContext.Entry(answer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                    }
                }

                dbContext.Answers.RemoveRange(answersToDelete);


                dbContext.Quests.First(x => x.Id == scene.QuestId).DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
            }
        }
```

This code works as indended, but I wonder is it best way to implement deleting answers, assuming I can't change the way scene designed or passed to my function?

Comment: It depends if an Answer can exist on its own and if Answer may be linked to another Scene.

Comment: @Jasen Answer **cannot** exists on it's own and one Answer can only be linked to single Scene.

Comment: You can delete these items yourself as you have or you can let the database handle it with cascade deletions.